# is there a function to show the only 4 digits in a column?

Tags: r

I'm trying to print out the first 4 digits out of a variable (rem1dt) bc it shows the year-month-day (e.g. 2019-12-03). I only want to year for each observation

```
  child2 <- child %>%
  filter( neglect == "Yes") %>%
  group_by(age, race, neglect, wait_time) %>%
  summarize(rem1dt = length(2019))%>%
  str_sub(rem1dt, 1,4) = '2019'
```

it gives me the error of

> Error in substr(., rem1dt, 1, 4): unused argument (4)

Comment: Do you mean `substr(., 1, 4)`?

Comment: I think `str_sub()` should work but you need something like `pull(rem1dt) %>% str_sub(1, 4)` ?

Comment: I would suggest to keep the date, but only present it as year by using `lubridate` package. `rem1dt <- as_date(rem1dt) %>% year()`

Comment: @Bloxx I tried your method but gave me an "error : error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as_date': object 'rem1dt' not found."                                                                          
 what i want to do is to make just produce only the year in the variable (rem1dt) for all

Comment: can you please provide your dataset? you can use `dput(child)` in your code and then paste the output as code in your question?

Comment: due to privacy of the data I cannot provide info of it @Bloxx i deleted the data and uploaded it again to try it

Comment: Actually you should double check the rem1dt variable type first, if its date, then convert it first to string, so then you can apply substring function to extract the string